# Artificial Neural Networks and Optical character recognitions

Tags: neural-network, ocr

Are **Artificial Neural Networks** used in 'Optical character recognitions' softwares?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please give some more context to your answer. This is a site for solving programming issues. Is your question related to programming in any way?

Answer (score 1):

They can be. I don't know what is the state of the art in commercial OCR but  artificial neural networks certainly can and have been applied to the problem.

Most often people use recurrent neural networks and specifically Hopfield networks. See for example:

- [A comparative study of neural network algorithms applied to optical character recognition](http://www.cs.unibo.it/~babaoglu/courses/cas04-05/papers/OCR.pdf)
- [Hopfield Networks: A Simple OCR Application](http://www.blendedtechnologies.com/wp-content/uploads/2006/05/Hopfield_Networks_A_Simple_OCR_%20Application.pdf)
- [High-Performance OCR forPrinted English and Fraktur using LSTM Networks](http://iupr1.cs.uni-kl.de/~shared/publications/2013-breuel-high-performance-ocr-for-english-and-fraktur-using-lstm-networks.pdf)

In the real world you will have to deal with many problems such as skewed images for which you'd maybe use special preprocessing. See

[The Anatomy of Bangla OCR System for Printed Texts Using Back Propagation Neural Network](http://www.academia.edu/1851487/The_Anatomy_of_Bangla_OCR_System_for_Printed_Texts_Using_Back_Propagation_Neural_Network) also tries to solve the problem of skewed images before running a neural network.

Feed-backpropagation neural networks could be used too: [training feedforward neural network for OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684204/training-feedforward-neural-network-for-ocr)

Another type of feedforward networks called [Convolutional neural network](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) have also been applied to OCR:

- http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/lenet/
- http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html

There is a comparison of different OCR techniques and their performance on the MNIST database of handwritten digits:

- http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/