# How is the number of hidden and output neurons calculated for a neural network?

Tags: neural-network, ocr

I'm very new to neural networks but I am trying to create one for optical character recognition. I have 100 images of every number from 0-9 in the size of 24x14. The number of inputs for the neural network are 336 but I don't know how to get the number of hidden neurons and output neurons.

How do I calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

While for the output neurons the number should be equal to the number of classes you want to discriminate, for the hidden layer, the size is not so straight forward to set and it is mainly dependent on the trade-off between complexity of the model and generalization capabilities (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network#Computational_power).

The answers to this question can help:
[training feedforward neural network for OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684204/training-feedforward-neural-network-for-ocr)

Answer (score 1):

The number of output neurons is simply your number of classes (unless you only have 2 classes and are not using the one-hot representation, in which case you can make do with just 2 output neuron).

The number of hidden layers, and subsequently number of hidden neurons is not as straightforward as you might think as a beginner. Every problem will have a different configuration that will work for it. You have to try multiple things out. Just keep this in mind though:

1. The more layers you add, the more complex your calculations become and hence, the slower your network will train.
2. One of the best and easiest practices is to keep the number of hidden neurons fixed in each layer.
3. Keep in mind what hidden neurons in each layer mean. The input layer is your starting features and each subsequent hidden layer is what you do with those features.
4. Think about your problem and the features you are using. If you are dealing with images, you might want a large number of neurons in your first hidden layer to break apart your features into smaller units.

Usually you results would not vary much when you increase the number of neurons to a certain extent. And you'll get used to this as you practice more. Just keep in mind the trade-offs you are making

Good luck :)